# NoMethodError: undefined method 'permit' for String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, axios, nomethoderror

I have a React SPA with a Rails API. I recently changed my API requests on the React side to go through `axios` instead of jquery and my `axios` setup is:

```
export default class API {
  static send(verb, resource, rawParams, callback, errcallback) {
    const params = Object.keys(rawParams).reduce((o, k) => {
      o[k] = rawParams[k];
      return o;
    }, {});

    const errorCallback = typeof errcallback === 'function' ? errcallback : () => {};

    const request = {
      method: verb,
      url: `${URL}/${resource}`
    };

    const token = window.sessionStorage.getItem('jwt');
    request.headers = {};
    if (token !== 'undefined' && token != null) {
      request.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }

    if (verb === 'GET' || verb === 'DELETE') {
      request.params = params;
      request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
      request.headers.Accept = 'application/json';
    } else {
      request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
      request.headers.Accept = 'application/json';
      request.data = params;
    }

    axios(request)
      .then(response => {
        if (resource === 'users/sign_in') {
          const jwt = response.headers.authorization;
          window.sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', jwt.split('Bearer ')[1]);
        } else if (resource === 'users/sign_out') {
          window.sessionStorage.removeItem('jwt');
        }
        callback(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        errorCallback(error.response.data);
      });
  }

  static baseURL() {
    return URL;
  }

  static get(resource, params, callback, errcallback) {
    API.send('GET', resource, params, callback, errcallback);
  }

  static post(resource, params, callback, errcallback) {
    API.send('POST', resource, params, callback, errcallback);
  }

  static put(resource, params, callback, errcallback) {
    API.send('PUT', resource, params, callback, errcallback);
  }

  static del(resource, params, callback, errcallback) {
    API.send('DELETE', resource, params, callback, errcallback);
  }
}
```

And to this I create a request such as:

```
API.get('user/user_auth', { validate_user: { user_type: 'gamer' } }. res => {
  ...
}
```

But now my Rails side fails in the permit param. The permit is defined as:

```
def user_type_params
  params.require(:validate_user).permit(:user_type)
end
```

And every time I do something like `user_type_params[:user_type]` in my Rails code I get an error such as:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "{\"user_type\":\"gamer\"}":String)`
```

It sends it as a string even though I added `request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';`. Is there some other way to convert the params properly before making the request?

Comment: Try just with `{ user_type: 'gamer' }` as payload on the client side. I believe you did not follow the rails convention in your controller. You should post the snippet of your controller. For example you have users controller, then you would do `params.require(:user).permit(:user_type)` then in the client side, the pay should only be `{user_type: "gamer"}

Comment: @tkhuynh If you check the def user_type_params which I defined above I check in the controller as params.require(:validate_user).permit(:user_type)

Comment: what is your controller name, please read more about rails controller and you will understand what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Axios escaping nested JSON is a known issue: [axios/issues/738](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/738).

The way to fix this was to add an interceptor in my `api.js` such as:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  config.paramsSerializer = params =>
    qs.stringify(params, {
      arrayFormat: 'brackets',
      encode: false
    });

  return config;
});
```

This ensures that the nested params are converted properly before sending them to Rails

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
def user_type_params
  json = params.require(:validate_user)
  {user_type: JSON.parse(json).permit(:user_type)}
end
```

Also, you don't necessarily need to use permit. You can whitelist the params yourself.

Comment: Is there a way I can edit this in the api wrapper class instead? If I change it on the rails side then I will have to change it everywhere

Comment: Try to `JSON.stringify` the params maybe?

Comment: That didn't fix it. I am still getting the same error :/

Comment: Also, this thing only fails in `staging` or `production` so I am not sure why that would be a thing either